# EF6 How to obtain data for DevExpress LookupEdit

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, entity-framework-6, devexpress

I have a table structured as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE employee
(
    employeeid integer NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    familyname varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    givenname varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    position varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    startdate date,
    address varchar(250),
    address2 varchar(250),
    city varchar(100),
    provincecd character(2),
    countrycd character(2),
    postalcode character varying(15),
    enddate date,
    employmentstatusid integer,
    photo bytea,
    dob date,
);
```

This table and several others are configured into a C# EF6 project.

I have a VB.Net WinForms project which uses the EF6 Entities as it's data store.

I am using a DevExpress XtraGrid control which I use to interactively populate my database.  The problem comes in where I need to provide data to a DevExpress LookupEdit control where I am using a subset of the data in my employees entity to populate the LookupEdit.  The data I want to use can be represented by the following SQL query:

```
    SELECT
    employeeid
    , concat(familyname, ', ', givenname) as fullname
FROM
    employee
WHERE
    employmentstatusid in (1,2)
ORDER BY
    familyname
    , givenname
```

I am not sure how to obtain the data using EF6 to populate my LookupEdit.

I am a neophyte when it comes to EF, but have worked with ADO.Net DataSets for many years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use LINQ to Entities to query an EF `DbContext`. In your case, it's going to be something like this:

```vb
Dim employeeNamesById = myDbContext.employees.
                                    Where(Function(e) {1, 2}.Contains(e.employeestatusid)).
                                    OrderBy(Function(e) e.familyname).
                                    ThenBy(Function(e) e.givenname).
                                    Select(Function(e) New With
                                                       {
                                                           e.employeeid,
                                                           .fullname = e.familyname & ", " & e.givenname
                                                       }).
                                    ToList()
```

That will create a generic `List` of objects of an anonymous type. You may prefer to define a class with the appropriate properties and create instances of that instead. Also, that code uses function syntax, which is generally my preference. You can use query syntax if you prefer, but I'll leave that to you if you want it.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  That looks like it would do exactly what I need.  Unfortunately, I get the following error: System.NotSupportedException
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Format(System.String, System.Object, System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: After a quick search on the error, corrected the query adding an "AsEnumerable()." just before the select.  This worked exactly as desired!  Thank you, much appreciated.

Comment: @ShaneBrodie, that's not the best solution. That's my mistake for forgetting that LINQ to Entities requires code that can be converted to SQL by the LINQ provider. I have updated my answer with the correct solution.